OpenVPN not working using UDP
I'm running OpenVPN on OpenWrt behind my ISP-provided NAT/gateway. I added a rule to forward TCP/UDP port number 1194 to my VPN server on the NAT. Everything works for TCP, but UDP does not seem to work. I get an IP address on the VPN client, but cannot ping the gateway (OpenWrt in this case).
Testing connectivity on port 1194 between a client and OpenWrt (via the public NAT IP) using netcat works using TCP but fails with UDP.
I added a rule to allow all UDP traffic on port 1194 to the firewall on the NAT, but it does not fix the problem.
